# Cannot Parse XML file using Python

Tags: python, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AcResponse
    Command="hist"
    TaskId="408709">
  <element
      name="/build.gradle"
      id="93527">
    <transaction
        id="1117194"
        type="promote"
        time="1529083792"
        user="soarfa99">
      <comment>Automated promotion to parent stream by module build: jenkins-SC-MODULE-CS-SC-TRUNK-MedRec-DEV-CI-430</comment>
      <version
          virtual="11007/75"
          real="36877/2"
          virtualNamedVersion="CS-SC-TRUNK-INTG/75"
          realNamedVersion="CS-SC-TRUNK-MedRec-DEV2_ar037601/2"
          elem_type="text"
          dir="no">
        <issueNum>72768</issueNum>
      </version>
    </transaction>
    <transaction
        id="1111652"
        type="promote"
        time="1528100495"
        user="dm041068">
      <comment>SEDA file add- Debajyoti</comment>
      <version
          virtual="11007/74"
          real="39225/1"
          virtualNamedVersion="CS-SC-TRUNK-INTG/74"
          realNamedVersion="CS-SC-TRUNK-CM-DEV-Debajyoti_dm041068/1"
          elem_type="text"
          dir="no">
        <issueNum>72629</issueNum>
      </version>
    </transaction>
  </element>
  <streams>
    <stream
        id="11007"
        name="CS-SC-TRUNK-INTG"
        type="normal"/>
  </streams>
</AcResponse>
```

This is the xml i am trying to parse, and i am trying to extract the attribute 'issueNum' with the following code:

```
tree=ET.parse(xml)
root=tree.getroot()
for item in root.findall('version'):
    for child in item:
        print(child.attrib['issueNum'])
```

Can you guys please help, get me the value of "issueNum".

Comment: `findall` will only find direct children. `version` is not a direct child of the root. Further, `issueNum` is not an attribute of `version`, so it won't find that one either.

Comment: `issueNum` is a tag, not an attribute. You need to use `find` or `findall`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [xpath expression](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method) to find the values of `issueNum`:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AcResponse
    Command="hist"
    TaskId="408709">....'''

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
issues = tree.xpath('//version/issueNum')

for issue in issues:
    print(issue.text)
```

This prints:

```
72768
72629
```

Comment: This gives an error like:

File "<string>", line 1
XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1

Comment: This though is now working:
tree=etree.parse(xml)
root=tree.getroot()
issues = tree.xpath('//transaction//version/issueNum')
for issue in issues:
    print(issue.text)

Comment: But now my question is, how do i get hold of the value of "virtualNamedVersion" from versions